# preg_match returns true for an invalid phone number

Tags: php, regex

Below is my code to verify a phone number. The issue is with an invalid phone number it still returns true. How can fix this?

```
$pattern = '/\(?[\d]{3}\)?\s?\-?[\d]{3}\s?\-?[\d]{4}/';
$str = array(
    "702 622 0277",
    "(702)622-0277",
    "702-622-0277",
    "(702) 622 0277",
    "1234", // false
    "7026220277",
    "+17026220277", // should be false
    "+17777036880277" // should be false
);
foreach($str as $each) {
    if(preg_match($pattern, $each, $matches)) {
        echo "$each is valid <br>";
    } else {
        echo "$each is invalid <br>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
702 622 0277 is valid 
(702)622-0277 is valid 
702-622-0277 is valid 
(702) 622 0277 is valid 
1234 is invalid 
7026220277 is valid 
+17026220277 is valid 
+17777036880277 is valid
```

Comment: Use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: Besides adding the anchors to fix the problem, you should clean up all the unnecessary characters that make your regex harder to read than it has to be: `^\(?\d{3}\)?\s?-?\d{3}\s?-?\d{4}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your string can match anything in the middle. So `+17026220277` matches because `7026220277` is at the end

Try this pattern

```
$pattern = '/^\(?[\d]{3}\)?\s?\-?[\d]{3}\s?\-?[\d]{4}$/';
```

`^` denotes the start of the string and `$` denotes the end

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! The answer will be marked "solved" after 9 minutes.